# Make form for model and model that belongs to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I want to have form for model Event and form for Game model which belongs to Event on single page. Problem is that I want to have single button for submit which would save Event and next Game which belongs to Event. How such form and controllers would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `form_for`, you can use the method [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for), like this:

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  #put your @event fields here
  <%= f.fields_for :games, @game do |g| %>
    #put your @game fields here, though you can also have the @event fields here too
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your `Event` model, add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :games` somewhere after your `has_many :games` line.

In your `EventController`, you need to add the game params to your strong params method:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:name, :time, :something_else,
                              games_attributes: [:score, :length, :whatever])
```